# Select target schema using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-schema

I created a database using MySQL Workbench, exported using Forward Engineering, and ran the script on the server.  I then went back to MySQL Workbench, and used Database/Synchronize Model With Database, however, it can't find the schema on target.  How do I select the target schema using MySQL Workbench?

[image]

[image]

```
-- MySQL Script generated by MySQL Workbench
-- 03/23/15 07:59:39
-- Model: New Model    Version: 1.0
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema test1
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `test1` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `test1` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `test1`.`table1`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test1`.`table1` (
  `idtable1` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idtable1`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turned out as a non-root user, I created a new user which would allow me to access the server remotely.  I've since dropped that user, and performed the same activity as root user, and can now select the schema.  Any suggestions why this is required would be appreciated.

```
CREATE USER 'bluepuppy1'@'192.168.1.10' IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'192.168.1.10' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```